# Airflow Scheduler stops scheduling tasks when max_active_runs_per_dag is set too high and high throughput

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I've tested this out pretty thoroughly at this point. I have scaled myself up to a ridiculous number of workers, down to a smaller number of workers with much more RAM and CPU, setting different configs back to defaults, etc. The only thing that is stopping Airflow from scheduling tasks is setting `max_active_runs_per_dag` to a value above 64, then scheduling over 64 executions of the same DAG. This is also happening with a rather beefy Scheduler instance. 4 cores, 16GB of RAM and using 2 threads.

Thanks!